# Como formatar a Data na GridView Asp.net C#

Tags: grid

Em asp.net c#,

Como faço para converter uma data na gridview vinda do banco para o formato `dd/mm/yyyy` ?
Atualmente ela fica como `18/05/2015 00:00:00`.
O tipo da coluna é BoundField.
Já tentei com `string.Format` e `DataFormatString="{0:d}` e não funcionou.
Desde já agradeço.

Att.

Comment: Veja esse post em inglês que trata do mesmo assunto.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832691/asp-net-formatting-datetime-in-gridview

Comment: Já consegui @PedroLaini, desse jeito em baixo funcionou, eu estava passando a data como string, ai mudei pra datetime e funcionou. Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="MyDate" 
 DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yy}">
```

Comment: Paulo, tentei e não pegou também DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yy}". Não teria algum jeito no código ?
Obrigado.